# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm running into an issue when trying to associate two records via a belongs_to:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offering,
    foreign_key: [:term_id, :class_number]
end

@enrollment = Enrollment.new
@enrollment.offering = Offering.last
```

This throws:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `[:term_id, :class_number]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you pass a single foreign key? (From the Rails standpoint, not from the data model standpoint.)

Comment: Yes, supplying a single key works but unfortunately I need two keys (I don't have control over the tables).

Comment: Yeah; I don't think Rails will automagically use multiple foreign keys, which is what the error message hints at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails unfortunately does not support composite keys. If you need something like this, you'd better go with a custom :has_many like @yannick's comment cites.

On the other side, you could do it with a model that's backed by a view, using a table (say `my_offerings`) which has a rails-friendly ID, and the two PK columns from the other table (`term_id`, `class_number`) and join it with the other table in code.

Then, have a small process that parses the `offerings` table, and builds any missing `my_offering` record.

In the end the view will have an ID, and the join in the view (that's transparent for rails) will deal with the composite key.